# An unknown syntax mistake in script which changes id of divs itsleft according to parent's title

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script which changes the class of div in li according to the title of parent page (means there is menu.html which is inside of iframe in home.html). Alas, I tried many things but it doesn't work. How can I find the mistake? Should I take in account that the captions aren't in English but in Hebrew?

The code for menu.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    switch (window.parent.document.title) {
        case "העמוד הראשי": document.getElementById("nada1").className="marked"; break;
        case "על הבנאי": document.getElementById("nada2").className = "marked"; break;
        case "בדיחות משעשעות": document.getElementById("nada3").className = "marked"; break;
        case "תוכנות חינמיות": document.getElementById("nada4").className = "marked"; break;
        case "קישורים מעניינים": document.getElementById("nada5").className = "marked";     break;
        default: alert("god damn!"); break;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<ul class="menu1">
<li><a href="Index.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada1">דף פתיחה</div></a></li>
<li><a href="About.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada2">על עצמי     ותחביבים</div>    </a></li>
<li><a href="Jokes.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada3">בדיחות</div></a>    </li>
<li class="nada4"><a href="freewares.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada4">תוכנות     חינמיות</div></a></li>
<li class="nada5"> <a href="Links.html" target="_parent"><div id="nada5">קישורים     שימושים</div></a></li>
</ul>
    <br /><br /><hr />
<div class="write_mail">אם ברצונך להרשם לעדכוני האתר, אנא הכנס את <br />כתובת המייל שלך     בצירוף שמך באנגלית:
    <form action="sent.php" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="subscr" /><br />email
        <input type="text" name="perosnal"/><br />שם
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="alert('good job and thanks!');"/>    </form></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the code for the index is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>העמוד הראשי</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<iframe src="menu.html" class="navibar" height="430px" width="50px" scrolling="no"     style="border-style:none"></iframe>
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="HomePage/suka1.gif"  height="200px" width="200px"     alt="מעט מידע בסיסי על חג סוכות"/></a>
<hr /><br />
<p class="About">i built it so respect!:)<br /> <a         href="mailto:me@gmail.com">לתלונות, מענות,פניות ושאר ירקות ופירות </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying elements before they exist on the page - move your script block into a `window.onload` handler and it should work fine:

```
window.onload = function () {
    switch (window.parent.document.title) {
        // snip ...
    }
};
```

Comment: i chnaged the head to 
    <head><script> window.onload=function(){...};</script> </head> and it still doesn't work. is there another thing?

Comment: @Zetathebeginner if you declare a script block before your HTML elements without an onload handler, the script will execute before the elements exist. `<head>` doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Comment: learned new thing:) even though i changed it into window.onload and still it refuses working....

Comment: @Zetathebeginner you're going to need to give a little more information. does the page load? are there any errors in the console? does the switch in the script block even execute?

Comment: ok. the home.html loads fine, doesn't show any error (both with ie9 and chrome). in the iframe the div of "nada1" dooesn't change its color to orange (as defined in style.css), seems the script doesn't execute(it doesn't pops up the message of defult case...), thanks again :)

Comment: @Zetathebeginner have you put a `debugger;` into the script and step through what it does?

Comment: i tried and it presents as usual the page, again without the script action...(same with 'run with dubbger' of visual studio)